# VuePress: Determine if running in context of pre-render or in browser

Tags: vuepress

In the logic of my Vue component in my VuePress site, can I determine whether it's running in the context of `vuepress build` generating the static HTML, or in the context of a genuine browser session?

My use case is I am using momentjs to format datetimes relative to the current datetime. eg. To say 'Yesterday' instead of '2020-04-03'.

The issue is the static HTML that VuePress generates at build time contains the phrase relative to the date on which the build was run. I want the static HTML to always contain the absolute, not the relative, datetime.

For human visitors to the site, Vue runs and replaces the pre-rendered date/phrase with the correct freshly calculated phrase/date and they are none the wiser.

For machine visitors that don't run the JavaScript, they see the pre-rendered relative phrase which is only correct on the day it was built.

Basically I want to do something like this:

```js
if (/* in context of vuepress pre-rendering */) {
  return 'content for static HTML'; // eg '2020-04-03'
}
// else, In context of visitors browser
return 'my dynamic content that depends on the date at view time'; // eg 'Yesterday'
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to separate your code into different life-cycle hooks to achieve that.

Generate the absolute time in the `created` hook of your Vue component, and then dynamically calculate the relative time in the `mounted` hook.

`created` will be called during both ssr and client. But code in `mounted` will only be executed [during client](https://ssr.vuejs.org/guide/universal.html#component-lifecycle-hooks)

Comment: Thank you. That works. I had discounted the SSR documentation as I'm not doing SSR, I'm per-rendering, and the docs indicate they're not the same - https://ssr.vuejs.org/#ssr-vs-prerendering